# Why inputStr === "" is always false?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper

I have this JavaScript code in my application:

```
var boo = function(inputStr) {
    if (!inputStr || inputStr === "") {
        throw new Error("Input is null or empty.");
    }
    return new Aftamat(inputStr);
};
```

And Resharper says that `inputStr === ""` is always `false`. Why? Is this the Resharper bug?

Comment: === checks for both value and datatype. "5" == 5 returns true. But "5" === 5 returns false because datatypes are different. Similarly in your above problem, if nothing is entered, it generates null datatype which is not equal to string. So, it returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if string is empty, it's kind of a false... so `!inputStr` will return true and actually your `inputStr === ""` will be never checked if your string is empty

Answer (score 1):

Probably because if `inputStr === ""` was true, then `!inputStr` would also be true, but if `!inputStr` was true, then `inputStr === ""` would never have been checked.

Ie, that code will only be reached in a situation where the test must be true.